# Python 'shelve' that writes itself to disk after each operation

Tags: python, persistence, shelve

I'm doing a project in Python that involves a lot of interactive work with a persistent dictionary. If I weren't doing interactive development, I could use contextlib.closing and be fairly confident that the shelf would get written to disk eventually. But as it stands there's no chunk of code that I can easily wrap within a 'with' statement. I'd prefer not to have to trust myself to call close() on my shelf at the end of a session.

The amount of data involved is not large, and I would happily sync a shelf to disk after each operation. I've found myself writing a wrapper for shelve that does just that but I'm not a strong enough Python programmer to identify the correct set of dict methods that I'd need to override. And it seems to me that if what I'm doing is a good idea, it's probably been done before. What is the paradigmatically correct way to handle this?

I'll add that I like using shelve because it's a simple module, and it comes with Python. If possible I'd prefer to avoid doing something that requires (for example) pulling in a complicated library for dealing with databases.

I'm using WinXP with SP3, Python 2.7.5 via Anaconda 1.6.2 (32-bit), and running inside Spyder. I can tell by looking at the modified times for the file backing my shelf that the shelf isn't updating until I call sync or close.

Comment: You could probably make it do this yourself since the source code for the `shelve` module is in `Lib/Shelve.py`.

Comment: Maybe you could use [atexit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html) to register a callback that closes the shelf when you exit your session.  I haven't used Spyder, so I'm not sure whether this would work there.

Comment: I think `atexit` makes a ton more sense, or look at the `writeback` keyword argument?  Actually flushing to disk every modification will likely carry huge I/O Bound Overhead.

Comment: @g.d.d.c: Since disk writes are probably cached, the i/o overhead probably would be acceptable. Beside that the OP said the amount of data is small, so syncing after each modification would be OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is subclass `DbfilenameShelf` and override `__setitem__` and `__delitem__` to automatically sync after each change.  Something like this would probably work (untested):

```
from shelve import DbfilenameShelf

class AutoSyncShelf(DbfilenameShelf):
    # default to newer pickle protocol and writeback=True
    def __init__(self, filename, protocol=2, writeback=True):
        DbfilenameShelf.__init__(self, filename, protocol=protocol, writeback=writeback)
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        DbfilenameShelf.__setitem__(self, key, value)
        self.sync()
    def __delitem__(self, key):
        DbfilenameShelf.__delitem__(self, key)
        self.sync()

my_shelf = AutoSyncShelf("myshelf")
```

I can't vouch for the performance of this, of course.

Comment: @kuzzooroo: This is another thing you can do if you can read the source (or it's documented well enough).

Comment: I don't think there's a need to overload `__init__()` if nothing is done but call the superclass' `__init__()`...

Comment: I thought it would be convenient to default to the newer `pickle` protocol and to having `writeback` on, so the caller doesn't need to specify those. Hence the `__init__()`.

Comment: Ah, yes, indeed -- sorry, obviously I missed those details. Personally I think it might be better to use the library's default argument values or point out the differences in a comment or docstring.